# pipe ripgrep search results to vim and open files at exact search location

Tags: vim, ripgrep

```
rg -l "searched phrase" | xargs vim
```

populates vim with searched terms, but I need to search for them once again, this time in vim.

How to pipe ripgrep search results to vim, so searched files will be opened at exact search location (line and column)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [Filling the quickfix window from stdin?](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/7ieb3p/filling_the_quickfix_window_from_stdin/) you can do the following:

```
rg --vimgrep 'pat' | vim -q /dev/stdin
```

You need to supply `--vimgrep` to get ripgrep's output into the correct format for Vim. `-q` reads a file into the quickfix list.

#### Alternatively

Do your searching from inside Vim via `:grep`

Add the following to your `vimrc` file:

```
set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
set grepformat^=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

Now you can do `:grep 'pattern'` and it will populate the quickfix list. Redoing your search is as easy as `:grep` followed by some `<up>` presses to get back to your relevant `:grep`.

#### Quickfix commands

- `:cnext`/`:cprevious` to navigate the quickfix forwards and backwards in the quickfix list
- `:cfirst`/`:clast` to jump to the start and end of the quickfix list
- Use `:copen` to open the quickfix window. Use `<cr>` to jump to an entry
- Use `:cclose` to close the quickfix window
- Use `:cc` to display the current error.
- `:colder`/`:cnewer` to jump older/newer quickfix lists

I would recommend you create mappings for `:cnext` and `:cprevious`. I personally use [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which provides `]q` & `[q` mappings for `:cnext` and `:cprevious`.

If you want the quickfix window to open automatically put the following in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup autoquickfix
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* lwindow
augroup END
```

There is a [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode about this topic: [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/).

#### Project-wide Search and Replace

If you are using `:grep`/`:vimgrep` as way to do a [project-wide search and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/) then I suggest you use `:cdo`/`:cfdo` (in Vim 7.4.980+).

```
:grep 'foo'
:cfdo %s/foo/bar/g|w
```

#### For more help see:

```
:h :grep
:h 'grepprg'
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :copen
:h :ccl
:h :cc
:h :colder
:h :cdo
:h :cfdo
```

Comment: in case someone else gets `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`, try `vim -q <(rg --vimgrep 'pat')` ... @LookAheadAtYourTypes in what way this doesn't answer? this seems like what you wanted based on your question

Comment: Second to `vim -q <(rg --vimgrep ...)`, I like this syntax better than piping in stdin.

This is also really handy for complex regexes that are difficult to work into Vim's idiosyncratic regex parsing.

Answer (score 1):

you can open vim with a command with the `-c` flag (see `vim --help`) 
It is easy to search with that:

```
rg -l "searched phrase" | xargs vim -c /searched phrase
```

But that will not jump to the exact position. A second `-c` will however assume that there is a second file open. So that we have to chain to jump behind the search:

```
rg -l "searched phrase" | xargs vim -c /searched phrase/norm n
```