# ripgrep from within vim's :term

Tags: vim, ripgrep

I often use `rg -i PATTERN | vim -` to pipe the results to a new vim session.

Is there a way to do this from within a running vim session with an open terminal (opened with `:term`) in a none blocking way?

I know `:vimgrep` and it's already configured to work with rg.

Is there a way to run multiple rg commands parallel from within?

I'm working on windows 10.

Update: The terminal from which I want to execute the commands is the terminal which is started from within Vim with the :term command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pipe ripgrep search results to vim and open files at exact search location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303484/pipe-ripgrep-search-results-to-vim-and-open-files-at-exact-search-location)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+ripgrep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for `:term rg -i PATTERN` which will run async and not block vim. It's also possible to run several commands in parallel.
And so the terminal is a buffer I can simply yank the results to my working document/buffer.